# how to locate unknown .vbe file currently running

Tags: installation, download, location, virus

the other day my little brother downloaded a game from somewhere, and as I caught him in the act of installing it, I noticed a little pop-up window in, like old windows graphics, popped up all sneaky and said "be now on auto start" or something close to that. So, is there any way I can find out what that was, where it is, or what it's doing, so I can see if it's a virus? thanks for your time and effort. the spell checker wont let me type v before "be on auto start"

Answer (score 0):

There is no surefire way to locate an unknown .vbe file that is currently running. However, some detective work may be able to uncover its location. Try checking recently accessed files, running processes, and open network connections to see if any clues can be found.